# Angularjs regular expression to restrict number of characters issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I have have the regular expression   `$scope.pa = /^([\w-~!@#\$]+)$/i` which is working fine for my requirements. Now I want to restrict this regular expression so that it can allow only 0 to 15 characters. So I have changed it to  `$scope.pa = /^([\w-~!@#\$]+){0,15}$/i;`
 but that 0 to 15 characters restriction is not working out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.2/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="controllerName">
        <ng-form name="mailForm">
             Pname: <input type="text" ng-model="pname" name="pname" ng-pattern="pa" /><br />
            <span ng-show="mailForm.pname.$error.pattern" style="color:red">Please enter pname</span>


        </ng-form>
    </div>
    <script>
    var app = angular.module("app", []);
    app.controller('controllerName', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
         $scope.pname = "abcd267g";
           $scope.pa = /^([\w-~!@#\$]+)$/i;

          }]);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `/^[\w\-~!@#\$]{0,15}$/i;`

Comment: Tushar, working fine and solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

> Now I want to restrict this regular expression so that it can allow only 0 to 15 characters.

To achieve this you should be applying range restriction on **character class [ ]** and not the **group ( )**.

Right now you have applied it to whole *group* `/^([\w-~!@#\$]+){0,15}$/i` which will **repeat infinite characters 0 to 15 times.** Which renders range restriction useless.

Thus, `{0,15}` should come after `[\w-~!@#\$]` and your regex will be:

`/^([\w\-~!@#\$]{0,15})$/i;`